# C strtok() not tokenizing correctly?

Tags: c, arrays, string, token, strtok

i've been trying to figure this out for a while now and i have absolutely no clue how to fix this. I have a pretty decent sized project and i'm using strtok countless times wihout any problems but it's not working here. Please Help :(

**Edit: i was looking for prefix removal and not strtok. I'm leaving this here if someone is confused and googles this.**

**This is the code in question:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char root[1000]; 
   char home[1000];

   strcpy(root,"/Users/me/Desktop/my-project"); // this is working
   strcpy(home,"/Users/me/Desktop/my-project/home"); // this is working

   strtok(home,root); // here's the problem

   printf("%s",home);
}
```

**Result 1:**

```
/Users/me/Desktop/my-project/h
```

**I've also tried:**

```
char *ptr = strtok(home,root);

printf("%s",ptr);
```

**Result 2:**

```
h
```

Shouldn't both return `/home` ?

Comment: I think you need to read up on `strtok` some more, the second argument is a pointer to a list of *single* characters to use as delimiters, it's not really suitable for removing common prefixes.

Comment: @paxdiablo ohh you're absolutely right, i've been using what you said throughout my project lol. I found a solution after you answered. Thank you :)

Comment: Jeffrey, you should post your solution as an answer and self-accept. That's perfectly okay by the SO guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @paxdiablo pointed out and as i was using it in my entire project (i haven't slept so forgive me), `strtok(char * str, char * delimiters)` takes a list of delimiters.

**What i was actually trying to do was remove the `root` substring from the `home` string.**

Since they will always start with the same substring `/Users/me/Desktop/my-project`, i can find the part unique to `home` right after `root` ends and that can be done like this really easily:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char root[1000]; 
   char home[1000];

   strcpy(root,"/Users/mbp/Desktop/my-project");
   strcpy(home,"/Users/mbp/Desktop/my-project/home");

   int n = strlen(root); // length of the root string

   // where to copy, from where to start copying, how many to copy
   strncpy(home, home + n ,strlen(home)-1); 

   printf("%s",home);
}
```

So what i do is:

1. get the length of root to know where it ends
2. override what's stored in home by copying the part from `home[n]` to `home[strlen(home)-1]`

**Result:**

```
/home
```

Comment: Why not simply `puts (strrchr (home, '/'));`?

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica that wouldn't work if let's say the user was in the home/desktop directory. i have to show him home/desktop and not just /desktop

Comment: If you cannot have more than one occurrence of `".../home/..."`, then just `puts (strstr (home, "/home"));`?